# Replace selected integer value with list of values with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has column "Survived".
That column has two possible values: 1 and 0.
I want to replace 1 with [1, 0] and 0 with [0, 1].

These are the ways I have tried to do it:

First convert column data type from int to object:

```
data["Survived"] = data["Survived"].astype(object)
```

Then try changing the value (they all work with integers, but not with lists):

```
data["Survived"][data["Survived"] == 1] = 5 # works
data["Survived"][data["Survived"] == 1] = [1, 0] # ValueError: cannot assign mismatch length to masked array
data["Survived"][::].replace(1, 5) # works
data["Survived"][::].replace(1, [1, 0]) # {TypeError}Invalid "to_replace" type: 'int'
```

And some other similar methods that result in these errors.

Oddly enough I can set values to list one by one.
So if I iterate over all entries I can change them all to lists (this gives the result I want):

```
for i, val in enumerate(data["Survived"]):
    data["Survived"][i] = [1, 0] if val == 1 else [0, 1]
```

This how ever, is slow and ugly. What is the pandas way of doing this?

Comment: Just wanted to add - your problem is related to how numpy broadcasts scalars into vectors. `data["Survived"][data["Survived"] == 1] = 5`, because value `5` is broadcasted to every relevant cell in your vector. `[1,0]` being vector of same dim but different shape cannot be broadcasted this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
Using `get_dummies`

```
df

   Survived
0         1
1         0
2         1
3         0
4         0
5         1
6         1
7         0

df['Survived'] = pd.get_dummies(df.Survived).values[:, ::-1].tolist()
df

  Survived
0   [1, 0]
1   [0, 1]
2   [1, 0]
3   [0, 1]
4   [0, 1]
5   [1, 0]
6   [1, 0]
7   [0, 1]
```

---

**Option 2**
Alternatively, with numpy indexing, assuming your column only has 0s and 1s.

```
i = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
df['Survived'] = i[df['Survived'].values].tolist()

df

  Survived
0   [1, 0]
1   [0, 1]
2   [1, 0]
3   [0, 1]
4   [0, 1]
5   [1, 0]
6   [1, 0]
7   [0, 1]
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
%timeit pd.get_dummies(df.Survived).values[:, ::-1].tolist()
1 loop, best of 3: 295 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit i[df['Survived'].values].tolist()
1 loop, best of 3: 273 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit np.where((df["Survived"] == 1)[:, None], [1,0],[0,1]).tolist()
1 loop, best of 3: 285 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit df.Survived.apply(lambda x: [0,1] if x == 0 else [1,0])
1 loop, best of 3: 368 ms per loop
```

All of these solutions are equally competitive. It's a matter of choice, which one you decide to use.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with broadcasting:

```
data["Survived"] = np.where((data["Survived"] == 1)[:, None], [1,0],[0,1]).tolist()
```

Answer (score 3):

If your dataframe only contains 0 and 1, you can use this:

```
data.loc[:, 'Survived'] = data.Survived.apply(lambda x: [0,1] if x == 0 else [1,0])
```

Check the type in the comparison

**EDIT**

IMO the answer based on `get_dummies` is not optimal, neither the one using `np.where` since you need to import numpy at your level.

Here's a benchmark of the elapsed time of the solutions proposed here using `apply`+`lambda`, `np.where` and `get_dummies`.

The x axis is the log10 of the number of rows (i.e. 7 means 1e7 rows = 10 million rows).

[image: Benchmark of the solutions]

Summing up:

- For smaller number of items, there is virtually no difference.
- **The best (slightly) performing solution is `np.where`, but you need to import numpy**
- The second best choice is `apply` very close to the first one.

**EDIT 2**

Setup here by request.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

perfdf = pd.DataFrame(index=[3, 4, 5, 6, 7], columns=['apply', 'where', 'get_dummies'])
for s in perfdf.index:
    data = pd.DataFrame({'Survived':np.random.randint(low=0,high=2, size=10**s)})

    tstart = time.time()   
    pd.get_dummies(data.Survived).values[:, ::-1].tolist()
    tstop = time.time()
    perfdf.loc[s, 'get_dummies'] = tstop - tstart

    tstart = time.time()
    np.where((data["Survived"] == 1)[:, None], [1,0],[0,1]).tolist()
    tstop = time.time()
    perfdf.loc[s, 'where'] = tstop - tstart

    tstart = time.time()
    data.Survived.apply(lambda x: [0,1] if x == 0 else [1,0])
    tstop = time.time()
    perfdf.loc[s, 'apply'] = tstop - tstart

perfdf
```

Comment: Just wanted to add, that apply in general loops through the data and tends to be slow. Whenever possible, try to use vectorised solution, like the one provided by @jezrael,

Comment: @jo9k If you downvoted my answer, and upvoted this, I'd like to understand why. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the post including a performance benchmark, since I did not agree to @jo9k 's comment.

Comment: I disagree with your hypothesis that apply is the best, and @jo9k is perfectly correct. I've added an answer that includes timings for everyone's methods. Also, where isn't the best performing solution, and it gets worse on larger data. I don't know what tests you did, but I cannot take any stock in them since you have not shared your setup. I would appreciate if you could back these lofty statements with some reproducible or convincing numbers, or not do so at all, thanks.

Comment: Okay, the first thing is that using the `time` module isn't as reliable as the `timeit` module. Also, would you kindly benchmark my second solution too? It seems to perform the best.

Comment: Furthermore, I ran your setup code, and `apply` is consistently the slow of the 3, _by far_.

Comment: Oh man, calm down. You may be right, in fact I believe so. I did the benchmark because I wanted to understand and came up with these numbers. I keep getting the same results. Now, before you spit fire I am honestly asking for the sake of knowledge, where am I wrong? Is there a bug anywhere in the setup? Did you run it as is and found a difference?